# Adding data to array from user input String

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a program that is supposed to have the user input a String containing a student's name followed by their quiz, homework and exam scores (user input determines how many of each for a student) and takes each piece of data and adds it to an array.

I was planning to do this by having 4 different arrays: 1 for names, 1 for HW scores, 1 for Quiz scores, 1 for exam scores.

How it works is for each student you enter the name followed by the scores with letters preceding each one indicating which kind of score it is. Example:

```
Bob Jones: e100 e95 e87 q10 q10 q8 h10 h10 h10
Joe Smith: q10 q10 h7 h10 h9 h10 e80
```

It seems easy enough to get the program to store each name in an array, but I am struggling with the code for getting it to pull e100, e95 etc. and put them in the exams array, for example. The code I have so far will obviously not do that and is instead set up to just add one integer to each array in the order they are entered:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeBook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to GradeBook!");
        System.out.println("Please provide grade item details");

        System.out.print("Exams (number, points, weight): ");
        int numExam = s.nextInt();
        int examPoints = s.nextInt();
        int examWeight = s.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Quizzes (number, points, weight): ");
        int numQuiz = s.nextInt();
        int quizPoints = s.nextInt();
        int quizWeight = s.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Homework (number, points, weight): ");
        int numHomework = s.nextInt();
        int homePoints = s.nextInt();
        int homeWeight = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("------------------");

        String names[] = new String [200];
        int examScores[] = new int [200 * numExam];
        int quizScores[] = new int [200 * numQuiz];
        int homeworkScores[] = new int [200 * numHomework];

        int students = 0;
        int e = 0;
        int h = 0;
        int q = 0;


    for (;;){


        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("1 Add student data");
        System.out.println("2 Display student grades & statistics");
        System.out.println("3 Plot grade distribution");
        System.out.println("4 Quit");

        int input = s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();

        if(input == 1){

            for(int i = 0; i <= students;){
                for (boolean done = false;done = true;){
                    System.out.println("Enter student data: ");
                    System.out.print("data>");
                    names[i] = s.next();
                    examScores[e] = s.nextInt(); 
                    quizScores[q] = s.nextInt();
                    homeworkScores[h] = s.nextInt();
```

edit1: Weights

This is how the user enters "grade item details" at the start of the program:

Exams (number, points, weight):3 100 60 (user presses enter)

Quizzes (number, points, weight):3 10 20 (user presses enter)

Homework (number, points, weight):3 10 20 (user presses enter)

The first number is the amount of exams/quizzes/homework in the course, second number is the max points for each exam/quiz/homework, the third number is the weight of exams/quizzes/homework in the final grade.

Comment: Your code example has weights, however your description does not mention weights at all. Could you clarify how the weights are entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If input is

```
Bob Jones: e100 e95 e87 q10 q10 q8 h10 h10 h10
```

And you recover it with:

```
names[i] = s.next();
examScores[e] = s.nextInt(); 
quizScores[q] = s.nextInt();
homeworkScores[h] = s.nextInt();
```

It will never work... Scores are not integers on your example (they are a String), you must parse the String and split it:

```
String readString = s.next(); // "e99"
char type = readString.charAt(0); // "e"
String sScore = readString.substring(1); // "99"
int score = Integer.valueOf(sScore);  // 99
```

[The code above has not been tested]

(see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

In general, your code is quite difficult to understand, and I think it is not complete on the question.

- Try to use methods and to comment key lines
- Use a constant for 200 (I imagine it's the number of students)
- Create Objects (Student, Score, ...)
- Use java Objects (HashMaps, Lists, ...)
- Use switch/case instead of if(input == 1)

Good luck! Start programming may be hard, but soon will be amazing.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm struggling with how to make it read more than one score in that manner. Won't it just add e99 for example to the exams array and then stop, ignoring the other scores?

Comment: To continue with other scores, you must put the code (or better call the method) processing each scores inside a loop.
The example I wrote just include how to get the value and the type of the score, not what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try storing the user input as a string, then using split() but I think using StringTokenizer to parse out the student name and scores would be better:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Once you have separated the student name from the scores, you can check the first character of each score; if the character is an "e", add the numeric part to the exams array; if it's "q", add to the quiz array; "h" goes to the homework array.

Some general suggestions:

I suggest you enable the program to keep entering the student data line by line until the user enters "END" or some other keyword.

The way you're setting up your arrays, there is no way to tell which student got what score. You will need to be able to do so for the other parts of the program.  I'd recommend making a Student class that has each student as an Object and records the scores as int arrays.

You could store the student data information in a hashmap but I think using arrays would be more appropriate for your level.

Once you have the Student class set up, you can make a Student array (call it "classroom" or something to that effect).  This classroom array will have a max size of 200 or whatever the max number of students is.  Whenever you add scores for a new student, you should be adding a corresponding Student object to the classroom array and making a note of their student ID.  The first student added will have a student ID of 1, the second will have student ID 2, and so on.  This is just so you can easily add more scores for existing students.  You will have to parse the user input differently to address this change.

User input for student data can now take the following forms:

- [studentName]: [score1, score2, ...]
- [studentID]: [score1, score2, ...]

Example:

(First time entering student data)

```
Bob Jones: e100 e95 e87 q10 q10 q8 h10 h10 h10
```

(User presses ENTER)

> > Bob Jones has StudentID 1.  Enter more student data or "END".

```
Joe Smith: q10 q10 h7 h10 h9 h10 e80
```

Then, if you want to add more scores to an already existing student, you'd refer to them using their student ID, so that

```
1: e90 h7 q8 q9 h10
```

would add these scores to the student with studentID 1, which would be Bob Jones.  Since arrays start at 0, the student ID for each student will just be 1 more than their index in the array (student 1 will be at index 0, student 2 at index 1, etc.).  The other (more complicated and less efficient) way would be to check the student name against each element in the array, adding more scores if the student already exists or adding a new Student object if they don't.

Since you can't change the size of arrays, you might run into problems when you ask the user for the total number of exams, quizzes, and homework for each student, assuming you implement the scores as variables of the Student class.  You should look up the differences between arrays and arraylist.  Make sure to stop the user from adding more scores than they specified in the beginning.

Comment: We haven't actually covered making a class containing objects like that so I have no clue how to go about doing that. I am really confused though about how I'm going to connect each line of scores with the name, and how I'm going to calculate each student's total score from the class. The directions also say that if all scores are not entered, those not entered will be added as 0's. Having trouble with that as well.

Comment: Start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/
When you use StringTokenizer, you can get each token by using nextToken().  A token will be something separated by a delimeter, in your case, a space.  This way, you can split up the user's input by student name and scores.

Comment: Other than this, I can't help you besides encouraging you to look around online and find examples to learn from.